# I get javascript error like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined when i click add note button

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have one textbox to bind data of entered note,but I when i clicked on save button it gives an error like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined.I didn't get the model,Means i get the model undefined.This below code is mixer of html and js,both have seprate file for understanding I post both together in question.

```
<html>
<input type="text" name="noteDetail" data-bind="value: noteDetail,source: notes" class="k-textbox" style="width: 700px; margin-top: 20px">                  
<div class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 20px;" data-role="button" data-bind="source: notes, events: { click: onNoteSave }">Add Note</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<br />
                <div id="noteGrid" 
                    data-role="grid" 
                    data-bind="source: notes,events: { save: onNoteSave }"                   
                    data-pageable="{refresh: true}"
                    data-selectable="true"
                    data-sortable="true"
                    data-editable="{
                        mode: 'inline'                
                     }"

        data-columns='[
            {field: "user", title: "Name"}, 
            {field: "noteDetail", title: "Notes"},
           {field: "creationTime", title: "Date & Time"}, 
            {command: [{name:"edit", template: kendo.template("<a class=\"k-button removebackground k-button-icontext k-grid-edit\" href=\"\\#\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil-square-o\" title=\"Edit\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a>")}], title: "&nbsp;"}                        ]'>
            <div data-role="pager" data-bind="source: notes"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
             <div>

      </html>
    </script> 
    onNoteSave: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.model.user = this.get("loginUserName");
    var gridData = $("#noteGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view();
    var noteGrid = $("#noteGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    },
    </script>
```

Comment: where you call it may not pass the model or model do not have the object user